# Can I use an ability increase across two abilities or just 1?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

When I level my paladin to level 4, I get an Ability Score improvement. Can I choose any ability score to improve? I can upgrade one by 2 or two by 1, correct?

Comment: This is a plain *read-the-book-to-me* question. You are supposed to read the book yourself. Please note that [we are not too fond](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions) of questions that only ask for answers that the book already gives.

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

You can choose which ability score(s) you want to increase. You can choose to increase one by 2, two by 1, or if your DM allows, choose a feat instead of the ability score upgrade.

Generally, you will choose an ability score that is related to your class (like Strength or Charisma for a Paladin), and most of the time it is better to take two points in one score, rather than one point in two different scores. Unless you have two odd scores you want to improve.

Also of note, you cannot increase an ability score over 20 with this feature (h/t [Javelin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/19580/javelin) for the reminder to include).